# Allow 4xx HTTP status codes in protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor, http-status-codes

I am developing a frontend with angular and started writing protractor e2e tests. The corresponding backend API might return 401, 404 or other client errors in some cases which is expected.

Here is a snippet where the login is tested:

```
it('should block unregistered users', () => {
  page.navigateTo()
  expect(page.showsLogin()).toBe(true);
  page.login("test", "test"); // http request against API happens here
  expect(page.showsLogin()).toBe(true);
});
```

The test fails because the api returns 404, but that is expected.

```
✗ should block unregistered users
  - Expected [ Entry({ level: SEVERE, message: 'http://localhost:4200/api/v1/auth - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)', timestamp: 1587332452811, type: '' }) ] not to contain <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ level: SEVERE }))>.
```

How can I make the test work? (I do not want to call the API directly from the test)

Or am I supposed to design my API and tests to only have 200s?

Comment: Is that definitely the correct test, I know it does appear to be based on the name? I'm curious why is it's printing `not to contain`. Do you know which one of those requests are failing?

Comment: I am quite sure it was the correct one. I just found the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes reading is hard. So I started with the default e2e test from angular and it also includes the following piece of code:

```
afterEach(async () => {
  // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
  const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
  expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
  } as logging.Entry));
});
```

I assume any client or server error codes are classified as severe logs. Uncommenting this turns the test green :)